# Apache on Mac fails with syntax error

Tags: macos, apache

I tried starting Apache on my Mac and it didn't work. So I did the thing were you get errors in the Apache and got this:

```
Syntax error on line 66 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so into server: dlopen(/Users/keeffefamily/Sites/libexec/apache2/mod_authn_file.so, 10): image not found
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: This is really strange. How have you installed apache httpd?

Comment: @hgiesel How do you do this, I can't find out anywhere (Sorry I'm kinda a newb at this)

Comment: Okay, it seems `httpd` is preinstalled on OS X. You should really go [with some online tutorial](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the `ServerRoot` directive within your `httpd.conf` file has an incorrect value. According to the error message, you have incorrectly set the path to `/Users/keeffefamily/Sites`.

Try changing the configuration directive in `httpd.conf` to read as follows:

`ServerRoot "/usr"`